# SQL USING LIKE IN JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table Books

```
  NAME  
   A
   B
   C
```

and another Booksassignment

```
ID   ASSIGNMENTTEXT
1     Book.Assigned.To:A
2     Book.Assigned.To:A
3     Book.Assigned.To:B
4     Book.Assigned.To:B
5     Book.Assigned.To:C
6     Book.Assigned.To:A
7     OtherText:A
```

I want to get how many books were assigned to each person e.g.

I should get

```
Person     Bookcount
A             3
B             2
C             1
```

**I ONLY WANT TO GET THOSE ROWS WHERE Book.Assigned.To:NAME**

I have tried using substring but I cannot solve

Thanks,

Aiden

Comment: Mysql or Sql-Server?

Comment: Horrible design. Have separate columns for the  ASSIGNMENTTEXT parts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use inner join and group by

```
select a.Name, b.count(*)
from Books a
inner join Booksassignment b on b.ASSIGNMENTTEXT  like concat('%:',  a.NAME)
group by a.Name
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it

Comment: Means I concat NAME of Book with Book.Assigned.To

Comment: @Aiden  ..no mean that  the a.Name (person Name i think ) is concatenated with % wildchar  and thi %:NAME is compare with like operator to the string Book.AssingnedTo:...... ..  this should match with concat pattern

Answer (score 0):

If length of name column is always 1, you can as the below:

```
SELECT
    B.Name AS Person,
    COUNT(1) Bookcount
FROM
    Books B INNER JOIN 
    Booksassignment  BA ON B.NAME  = BA.RIGHT(ASSIGNMENTTEXT, 1)
GROUP BY
    B.Name
```

Comment: I want to do like this  WITH Books AS
(
       SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM Books
)

SELECT DISTINCT Books.Books, COUNT() FROM Books
LEFT OUTER JOIN BookAssignment ON Books.NAME = BookAssignment.ASSIGNMENTTEXT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        REPLACE(AssignmentText,SUBSTRING(AssignmentText,0, CHARINDEX(':',AssignmentText,0)+1),'') AS AssignedName
    FROM @tblBooksassignment
)
SELECT
    B.Name,
    COUNT(T.Id) AS 'PersonBookCount'
FROM T
INNER JOIN @tblBooks B ON B.Name=T.AssignedName
GROUP BY B.Name
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #T(nAME varchar(25))
INSERT INTO #T
SELECT 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' 

CREATE TABLE #tt (Id int,Book Varchar(25),Name Varchar(255))
INSERT INTO #tt
SELECT 1,'Book.Assigned','A' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Book.Assigned','A' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Book.Assigned','B' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'Book.Assigned','B' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'Book.Assigned','C' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'Book.Assigned','A' 


SELECT #tt.Name,COUNT(#tt.Name)  from #tt INNER JOIN #T 
ON #t.Name=#tt.Name 
GROUP BY #tt.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this will work

```
SELECT B.NAME,
       COUNT( * ) as Bookcount

  FROM Books B

  JOIN Booksassignment BA
    ON B.NAME = SUBSTRING( BA.ASSIGNMENTTEXT, -1 )
   AND BA.ASSIGNMENTTEXT LIKE 'Book.Assigned.To:%'

 GROUP BY B.NAME
```

Comment: Means I want to user SUBSTRING in NAME of Book with Book.Assigned.To

Answer (score 0):

If name is allways in the end of the `ASSIGNMENTTEXT` column use `right` function

```
select name, count(*) from Books b
    inner join Booksassignment a on b.name like RIGHT(a.ASSIGNMENTTEXT, 1)
where ASSIGNMENTTEXT like 'Book.Assigned.To:%'
group by name
```

**Update ANSWER**
If you need first column to be "Book.Assigned.To:":

```
select ASSIGNMENTTEXT, count(*) from Books b
        inner join Booksassignment a on b.name like RIGHT(a.ASSIGNMENTTEXT, 1) 
where ASSIGNMENTTEXT like 'Book.Assigned.To:%'
group by ASSIGNMENTTEXT
```

Exemple:

```
with Books as (select * from ( select 'A' as name union select 'B' union select 'C' ) as b )
, Booksassignment as (
    select * from (
        select 1 as iD,  'Book.Assigned.To:A'  ASSIGNMENTTEXT union 
        select 2, 'Book.Assigned.To:A'  union 
        select 3, 'Book.Assigned.To:B'  union 
        select 4, 'Book.Assigned.To:B'  union 
        select 5, 'Book.Assigned.To:C'  union 
        select 6, 'Book.Assigned.To:A'
    ) as c
)
select name, count(b.name) as ASSIGNMENTs from Books b
    inner join Booksassignment a on b.name like RIGHT(a.ASSIGNMENTTEXT, 1) 
group by name
```

Comment: I want to include Book.Assigned.To:

Comment: Means I concat NAME of Book with Book.Assigned.To:

Comment: Book.Assigned.To: will always come and there could be other texts in AssignmentText. e.g. ABCD.DEF:. so I want only those rows where Book.Assigned.To:NAME

Comment: Use 'where ASSIGNMENTTEXT like 'Book.Assigned.To:%''

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on Mysql :

SELECT  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(o.ASSIGNMENTTEXT,-1) ,' ', COUNT(`ASSIGNMENTTEXT`)  )  FROM `Booksassignment`  AS o GROUP BY `ASSIGNMENTTEXT`

Comment: I want to use SUBSTRING NAME of Book with Book.AssignedTo: and concat it for each row